# Python: Counting cumulative occurrences of values in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    fruit
0  orange
1  orange
2  orange
3    pear
4  orange
5   apple
6   apple
7    pear
8    pear
9  orange
```

I want to add a column that counts the cumulative occurrences of each value, i.e.

```
    fruit  cum_count
0  orange          1
1  orange          2
2  orange          3
3    pear          1
4  orange          4
5   apple          1
6   apple          2
7    pear          2
8    pear          3
9  orange          5
```

At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
df['cum_count'] = [(df.fruit[0:i+1] == x).sum() for i, x in df.fruit.iteritems()]
```

... which is fine for 10 rows, but takes a really long time when I'm trying to do the same thing with a few million rows. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`groupby`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNwvboxIHLAhXH8HIKHZHKD_cQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.groupby.html&usg=AFQjCNHHSSvCFAsKgv2N7zIvoBjcMcFMJg&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGQ) and [`cumcount`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH7NzxxIHLAhXDc3IKHf_jCzMQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html&usg=AFQjCNEqEc-1tDfxONX_eIS8DhzAOFansg&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGQ):

```
df['cum_count'] = df.groupby('fruit').cumcount() + 1

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
    fruit  cum_count
0  orange          1
1  orange          2
2  orange          3
3    pear          1
4  orange          4
5   apple          1
6   apple          2
7    pear          2
8    pear          3
9  orange          5
```

**Timing**

```
In [8]: %timeit [(df.fruit[0:i+1] == x).sum() for i, x in df.fruit.iteritems()]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.76 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit df.groupby('fruit').cumcount() + 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 926 µs per loop
```

So it's faster in 4 times.

Comment: Sorry, but why use my solution in your timing? Please add your solution or remove timings.

Comment: @jezrael yeah, sorry. Wrong copy.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe better is use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with specify column, because it is more efficient way:

```
df['cum_count'] = df.groupby('fruit' )['fruit'].cumcount() + 1
print df

    fruit  cum_count
0  orange          1
1  orange          2
2  orange          3
3    pear          1
4  orange          4
5   apple          1
6   apple          2
7    pear          2
8    pear          3
9  orange          5
```

Comparing `len(df) = 10`, my solution is the fastest:

```
In [3]: %timeit df.groupby('fruit')['fruit'].cumcount() + 1
The slowest run took 11.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 299 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit df.groupby('fruit').cumcount() + 1
The slowest run took 12.78 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 921 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit [(df.fruit[0:i+1] == x).sum() for i, x in df.fruit.iteritems()]
The slowest run took 4.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.72 ms per loop
```

Comparing `len(df) = 10k`:

```
In [7]: %timeit df.groupby('fruit')['fruit'].cumcount() + 1
The slowest run took 4.65 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 845 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit df.groupby('fruit').cumcount() + 1
The slowest run took 5.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 1.59 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit [(df.fruit[0:i+1] == x).sum() for i, x in df.fruit.iteritems()]
1 loops, best of 3: 5.12 s per loop
```